# "Значение типа const char* нельзя присвоить сущности типа char*" от чего зависит возникновение или невозникновение данной ошибки?

Tags: c++, строки, visual-c++

В ряде вопросов на ruSO, например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1215535/344284), а также в вопросах на CyberForum (например, [вот](https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread2167608.html)), да и в целом на просторах интернета многие люди сталкиваются с проблемой, описанной в заголовке вопроса. Как исправить её, я знаю из тех же вопросов. Почему возникает, тоже в курсе. Вопрос в другом – почему не возникает у меня?

Если подробнее: попытался для решения вопроса по первой ссылке воспроизвести проблему, чтобы проверить своё решение, а потом уже написать его в ответ. И столкнулся с тем, что у меня прекрасно и без каких-либо проблем работает то, что вызывает вопросы у других. Например, такой простой код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char * x = "Hello";
    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

компилируется без проблем и, как и ожидалось, выводит "Hello" как на VS 2015, так и на VS 2008.

Ещё раз вопрос: почему у меня не воспроизводится описанная выше проблема и `const char *` без проблем присваивается `char *`? Каковы условия возникновения данной ошибки?

Comment: Вероятно, потому что у вас не очень свежая студия? =)

Comment: По указанной вами же ссылке на киберфорум расписано, что сталкиваются с проблемой в более свежих версиях студии, которые работают по более свежим стандартам С++. И там же расписано, как с этой конкретной ошибкой бороться (несколькими способами, от приведения типов, до настройки компилятора).

Comment: @vp_arth, возможно. На 19ой потестить пока руки не дошли. Но неужто с новыми стандартами настолько кардинально пересмотрели взгляды на подобные присвоения? Как говорит kleshenki, не в студии дело.

Comment: @kleshenki, как бороться я понимаю. Я не пойму, почему мне не приходится этого делать ни на одной из студий.

Comment: Ну как же не в студии, дело в стандарте) И это не ошибка, а diagnostic message

Comment: Потому что 2015 студия это откровенно говоря немного старовато уже, а 2008 я вообще молчу) И сделано это по всей видимости не чтобы костылей наставить разработчикам, а для защиты от неверных обращений к памяти. К тому же, новому компилятору, насколько я знаю, можно явно указать более старый стандарт для работы.

Comment: @vp_arth, Тогда не могли бы Вы рассказать в ответе, как работало данное присвоение раньше и как работает в современных стандартах? И в каком стандарте произошёл "роковой перелом"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта проблема существовала давно. Однако версии Visual Studio до 2013 реализовали нестандартное поведение и разрешали навалидную инициализацию указателя без `const` квалификатора строковым литералом. Затем они приняли курс на соответствие стандартам и в Visual Studio 2013 появилась возможность включаить конформное поведение посредством аргумента [`/Zc:strictStrings`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-strictstrings-disable-string-literal-type-conversion?view=msvc-160). А начиная с Visual Studio 2017 появился режим общего соответствия стандартам [`/permissive-`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-160), который теперь используется по-умолчанию при создании новых проектов.

Кроме того, был исправлен еще один случай не конформного поведения - попытка напрямую инициализировать `bool` строковым литералом `bool foo{"foo"};` теперь корректно распознается как ошибка.

Comment: Ещё Visual Studio может указатель на функцию неявно преобразовать в `void*`, хотя по стандарту такие финты можно проделывать только через `reinterpret_cast`. Но это тоже можно исправить какими-то ключами (какими именно сходу не скажу)).

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл по стандарту такого преобразования раньше вообще не допускалось, а сейчас вроде как отдается на откуп реализации.